# Detect when background sound end

Tags: vb.net

i'm using:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play("Sound.wav")
```

For playing background sound. I want to detect when it end to raise an event

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing it in a backgroundworker? On the do work event play the sound with wait until end, and then on the work complete event put

```
msgbox("Music finished playing, press OK to loop")
backgroundworker.RunWorkAsync()
```

Sorry if the codes not exact, I can't remember this all off by heart.

Comment: `RunWorkerAsync()` starts the BGW again, you probably don't want that in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event... Otherwise a good answer!

Comment: i used a timer, then set timer interval is same wav file duration. It solved!